# Как помочь предложению знаками, не переписывая?

Tags: пунктуация

> Форум Траяна теперь мы делим на составляющие, называем сохранившуюся
>   часть его «рынок», хотя на самом деле перед нами возвышается здание
>   административного управления, кладовые и помещения форума,
>   непосредственно здесь проходила раздача оливкового масла, хлеба и вина
>   – доля урожая, на которую имел право каждый гражданин Рима.

Что я исказила, прав*ю*чи (не нашла как пишется)?

*Форум Траяна теперь мы делим на составляющие, называем сохранившуюся часть его «рынок» (хотя на самом деле перед нами возвышается здание административного управления, кладовые и помещения форума): непосредственно здесь проходила раздача оливкового масла, хлеба и вина – доля урожая, на которую имел право каждый гражданин Рима.*

Может, ошибочно внесла в скобки "кладовые и помещения форума"? О_о

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скобки стоят нормально, отделяют добавочную информацию от основного содержания:

Форум Траяна **мы теперь** делим на составляющие, **называя** сохранившуюся часть его «рынок» (хотя на самом деле перед нами возвышается здание административного управления, кладовые и помещения форума): непосредственно здесь проходила раздача оливкового масла, хлеба и вина – доля урожая, на которую имел право каждый гражданин Рима.

Comment: А не может быть такого, что *кладовые и помещения форума,* внесённые мною внутрь скобок, тоже упомянутые ***составляющие***? Авторский текст может быть прочитан иначе?

Comment: От форума Траяна полностью сохранились только мемориальная колонна и рынок. Там были другие сооружения: Первоначальный форум Траяна, состоявший из площади, базилики Ульпия и мемориальной колонны между биб­лиотеками, был освящен в 113 году. Входная ар­ка была сооружена через четыре года., а храм Гения Траяна – уже после смерти императора.  https://studopedia.ru/2_128985_forum-trayana-triumfalnaya-kolonna-trayana.html . Наверное, все эти несохранившиеся постройки  и есть составляющие

Answer (score 1):

Продираясь сквозь частокол слов, с трудом начинаю понимать смысл прочитанного: *называем сохранившуюся часть «рынок», хотя на самом деле это не рынок, а называем ее так потому, что здесь проходила раздача продуктов.*

Предлагаю переделать так, чтобы облегчить читателю жизнь.

Форум Траяна мы теперь делим на составляющие, называя сохранившуюся **его часть** «рынок», хотя на самом деле перед нами возвышается здание административного управления, кладовые и помещения форума. **Это название объясняется тем, что** непосредственно здесь проходила раздача оливкового масла, хлеба и вина – **той долИ** урожая, на которую имел право каждый гражданин Рима.